# Algorithms for minimum vertex cover

Tags: graph-theory

The algorithm I am trying is called Clarkson's greedy algoritm (located on page 98 in [lecture notes](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/samir/2012lecnotes.pdf)).

Given initial data of

[image: initial]

with each vertice having a weight of 1, the algorithm calculates the minimal cover (1, 3, 4, 5) but not the minimum (2, 4, 5).

Am I misusing the algorithm or is it supposed to only calculate an approximate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a not located on the next page after one more greedy algorithm:

> Note that both these algorithms come up with a maximal packing (or maximal dual solution) and pick
>   those vertices in the cover for which the dual constraint is met with equality. Any method that comes up
>   with such a maximal dual solution would in fact yield a 2 approximation. These are just two ways of defining
>   a maximal dual solution.

So Clarkson's greedy algorithm is stated to be $2$-approximate.

Comment: Does this answer my question? I.e. can an algorithm that's 2-approximate only return an approximate solution?

Comment: @Simas Yes, 2-approximate algorithm guarantees only that the provided solution is at most 2 times worse than the optimal one. It is obviously impossible to get an optimal solution of minimum vertex cover problem (that is NP-hard) in polynomial time unless $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$.